# Find key from value in associative array containing JSON

Tags: javascript, arrays

I've searched and found a few similar-but-not-quite answers.

I have an array `SongList` (showing 2 items for brevity...) - the first pair is a key, the second pair is some JSON.

```
SongList={
    song_1:{title:"title of first song",artist:"the artist",mp3:"http://mysite/song1.mp3"},
    song_2:{title:"title of second song",artist:"the artist",mp3:"http://mysite/song2mp3"}
    ...
};
```

I would like to be able to retrieve the key (`song_1` or `song_2`) given the `title` in the value.

I will be looping through a temporary array of `i` items, each item in this array would have a match in `SongList` and I would save the key (`song_1`, `song_2`) in a final array.

Comment: I'm not sure what the issue is; iterate over the key/value pairs in the "list", check the title, if it matches, push it onto the result array.

Comment: Iterate over the properties of `SongList` and compare the `title`.

Comment: Can there be different songs with same title?

Comment: @hindmost But there is no array. `SongList` is an object of objects.

Comment: FYI, what you have is a JavaScript object, not JSON. JSON is **text**, not data structures.

Comment: @Oriol: The 'array' is SongList itself - he can iterate over its members looking at title

Comment: @Oriol no, each title is unique. Felix, Thank you, I'm sure that wa s at the root of my problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks everyone, I realize my understanding of Arrays v. Objects was an issue which obviously hindered my Google-Fu. I hope it's ok to post the answer I finally arrived at via guidance here:

(SongList object is described in question above)

This is the eventual function I arrived at for saving the keys of the playlist SongList:

```
$("#save_playlist_as_keys").click(function() {
var keys = []
for(var i=0; i<myPlaylist.playlist.length; i++){
   var playItem = (myPlaylist.playlist[i].title); //this returns the names of the tracks
   for (var k in SongList){
      if(SongList[k].title == playItem) keys.push(k);//this matches track name to keys
    }
}
localStorage.setItem('storedKeys',keys); 
});
```

This seems to be doing what I want for now.

Answer (score 5):

You don't have an array, you have an object, containing more objects. Use `for in`

```
function findTitle(title) {
    for (var key in SongList) {
        if (SongList[key].title == title) return key;
    }
    return false;
}
```

And then call it!

```
findTitle("title of first song"); //returns "song_1"
findTitle("BNOT MEEEEEE"); //returns false
```

Comment: thanks, the matching key to title line helped immensely although I never got the return key to work. I ended up pushing the matches to an array.

Comment: @dijon -- Ahh, I can edit this to accommodate for more than 1 match if ya need it - and return the array

Comment: thanks but in my case there isn't a need more than one match and I think I got the array figured out in my answer above.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example.

```
var one = {
 a: {b:"MightyMouse", d:2},
 b: {b:"MickeyMouse", d:4},
 c: {b:"Superman", d:6}
};

for (outerkey in one) {
    if (one[outerkey].b === "Superman") {
         console.log ("Outerkey = " + outerkey);
    }
}
```

Assuming you are looking for `Superman`, this prints as expected `c`.